# Infinite sum of partial sums

Tags: sequences-and-series

If, for an infinite sequence $a_1, a_2, a_3...$ we say that the partial sum is: $$\sum_{i}^n a_i$$
could the sum of the partial sums converge (retaining a constant first term, or $a_1$? That is, is there a sequence such that: $$\sum_{n=i}^\infty \sum_{i}^n a_i$$ converges? I could only think if all terms equaled $0$, because each term would be added repeatedly, and thought that none of the terms could be nonzero. Is my thinking right on that?

Thank you kindly!

(Apologies about any issues with the equations; I'm new to MathJax and the website in general).

Comment: I'm confused about the use of indexes here. What's the range of $i$ and what's the range of $n$?

Comment: In order for the partial sums of a sequence to converge, the sequence itself must tend to zero. So you'd need to start with a sequence whose partial sums themselves tend towards zero. It should be possible to engineer this, but it usually won't happen.

Comment: Noy Soffer: Sorry, I wasn't sure about the notation for "undefined" initial terms. The lower bound is just any general number that the sequence exists for (for example, if $a_n = \sqrt(n)$, you could say the first term could be 0, 1, 2...) and I suppose that the upper bound would be another arbitrary number not less than the lower bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can turn the question around a bit: Supposing that we have some sequence $\{s_n\}$, can we find another sequence $\{a_n\}$ with partial sums $\{s_n\}$? It's easy to see that this is indeed true. For example, suppose we have the geometric sequence $\{s_n\}=\{1,\frac12,\frac14,\frac18,\cdots\}$. Then by inspection these are the partial sums of the sequence $\{a_n\}=\{1,-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{4},-\frac{1}{8},\cdots\}$.